# Differences between DEV and PRO in using /usr/sap/trans

Tags: sap-basis, sap-r3

I am configuring transport System, PRO is the domain controller.

I recently made a 46C system copy/installation from PRO (production) to DEV (development/test) system and need to reconfigure transport system.  After the copy two domain controllers exists, one in DEV and another in PRO. I have 2 questions here:

1. Using `STMS`, should I delete DEV domain controller and create another that only integrate to PRO domain controller?
2. After this, will the `/usr/sap/trans` in DEV be populated with new transport orders/tasks generated in this system? or only `/usr/sap/trans` of PRO will be populated with DEV transport orders/tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Regarding your question in the comment. **Both** system should look at the same directory. Sap is never transfering files from one trans directory to another. The process is:

- You release a request from dev system. This create files in /usr/sap/trans/(data & cofiles).
- If your stms is configured correctly (another complex issue), you immediately see the request on the prd system import queue and can import it.
- If the route in stms is not configured. You can still add the request to the prd system queue. and then import it to prd.

There is not file movement involved. Since both system look at the same directory tree.

Here is [Sap documentation on stms](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw2004s/helpdata/en/14/94fc3f8fc2c542e10000000a1550b0/frameset.htm). Its not simple. But you can test and play with it untile you grasp the concept.

**Before update:**The usual practice is:

1. There should be only one domain controller in your landscape. And one backup domain controller.
2. All system should point to the same trans directory.

Comment: Thanks Igal. In relation to question 2, let me understand one thing please: in DEV I create an order request, when I release it, /usr/sap/trans/(data & cofiles) in DEV is populated with transport files. Then, in PRO I transport the order of DEV, meaning that resquests of DEV is transferred to PRO /usr/sap/trans/(data & cofiles). At that moment I have redundant info in DEV and PRO at the OS level about transport files, is that correct? should it work as I describe you? Thanks again!!